# add newwatermark in blankpage

Tags: positioning, compiling, blank-page, watermark, xwatermark

I'm new to latex and I'm having trouble adding a watermark to the last (non-numbered) page of my document. I'm using the xwatermark package, but I can't compile my document. The commands I used are before the beginning of the document.
follow my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}% Margens

\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}           % Para criar anexar links
%\usepackage{lmodern}                   % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{subfigure}                  % Adicionar subfiguras
%\usepackage{fontawesome}               % Fonte e simbolos
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos
%\hypersetup{colorlinks = true}         % Colorir Links
%\usepackage{nomencl}                   % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
%\usepackage{showframe}                 % Mostra margens
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\usepackage{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[pages=8,color=black!10,angle=60]{RASCUNHO}



\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            myrectangle/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=160, minimum height=40, thick, rounded corners=5, black}
            ]
            
            \node[myrectangle] (a) at (0,0) {
                \hspace{0.50cm}
                \begin{minipage}{0\textwidth}
%                   \includegraphics[scale=.4]{./figuras/CEFETMG_vetorizada.pdf}
                \end{minipage}
            \hspace{0.9cm}
                \begin{minipage}{0.90\textwidth}
                    {\centering CENTRO FEDERAL DE EDUCAÇÃO TECNOLÓGICA DE MINAS GERAIS
                                    \vspace{0.2cm}\\
                    CAMPUS CURVELO\\}
                %1ª lista de exercícios do 3° bimestre – 1ª ano\\
    %\centering Prof. Ulisses Moreira
                \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\vspace{0.8cm}

%\centering 2ª lista de exercícios do 4° bimestre - 1° ano - Prof. Ulisses Moreira
%
%\vspace{0.4cm}
%
%\centering \normalsize \textbf{Energia mecânica}
%
%
%
%\vspace{0.4cm}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\underline{1° trabalho da recuperação em física - 1° ano}}
\end{center}

{Prof. Ulisses Moreira \hspace{4cm} Valor: 25 pontos \hspace{4.55 cm}   Data: 14 / 12 / 2022\\

Nome: \rule[0cm]{15cm}{0.1pt} \hspace{0.05cm} 
Nota: \rule[0cm]{1.5cm}{0.1pt}\\
\vspace{-0.15cm}
\begin{center}
    {\small \textbf{\underline{Observações}}}
\end{center}


\begin{enumerate}[label={*}]
    \item {\small Trabalho individual;}
    \vspace{-0.1cm}
    \item {\small Não é permitido o uso de eletrônicos (celulares, calculadoras, etc.);}
    \vspace{-0.1cm}
    \item {\small Deixe claro o raciocínio utilizado, questões sem o desenvolvimento não serão consideradas.}
\end{enumerate}

\footnotesize
\begin{enumerate}
    
\item Uma pedra é lançada do alto de um edifício, que possui altura $h_{0}$, com velocidade inicial $\vec{v}_{0}$, de módulo igual a 30 m/s, que forma um ângulo de 30° com a horizontal, como ilustra a figura abaixo.

Considerando g = 10 m/s$ ^{2} $, $h_{0}$ = 50 m, sen30° = 0,5 e cos30° = 0,87, encontre:
%\vspace{-.5 cm}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item as velocidades horizontal e vertical da pedra no instante do lançamento.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a função horária da posição ao longo da direção horizontal.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a função horária da posição ao longo da direção vertical.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a função horária da velocidade ao longo da direção vertical.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,5.5);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \item a velocidade da pedra no ponto mais alto da trajetória.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,5.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item o tempo necessário para que a pedra atinja a altura máxima.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,5.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a altura máxima.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,5.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\pagebreak
    \item o tempo total, ou seja, o tempo que a pedra gasta para atingir o solo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,16);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item o alcance horizontal.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item o módulo da velocidade vertical da pedra imediatamente antes de tocar o solo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\

\newpage

Para os itens a seguir, tome cuidado de colocar nos gráficos os pares ordenados das grandezas pedidas. Não se esqueçam de identificar os eixos com suas respectivas unidades. \\

    \item Trace o gráfico da posição horizontal em função do tempo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item trace o gráfico da posição vertical em função do tempo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
    \item Trace o gráfico da velocidade vertical em função do tempo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item Trace o gráfico da aceleração, ao longo do eixo $y$, em função do tempo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item Trace o gráfico da aceleração, ao longo do eixo $x$, em função do tempo.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\newpage

\item A polia $A$ de raio 0,30 m, que está fixada no eixo 1, executa 20 voltas em 5,0 s. Ela está ligada por meio de uma correia à polia $ B $, que possui um raio de 0,20 m. A polia B e C estão ligadas ao eixo 2 e o raio da polia $C$ é igual a 0,40 m. Baseado nessas informações, determine:\\
\textbf{Considere $\pi$ = 3.}

%
%\begin{figure}[H]
%   \centering
%   \includegraphics[scale=2]{figuras/MCU}
%\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item a frequência do movimento da polia $A$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item o período do movimento da polia $A$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a velocidade angular da polia $A$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a velocidade tangencial do ponto $P$, que está na borda da polia $ A $.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \item a velocidade tangencial do ponto $Q$, que está na borda da polia $B$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage
    \item a velocidade angular da polia $B$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a frequência do movimento da polia $B$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%   \item o período do movimento da polia $B$.\\
%   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
%       \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,3);
%   \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a velocidade angular da polia $C$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \item a velocidade tangencial do ponto $R$, que está na borda da polia $C$.\\
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%   \item a distância percorrida pela ponto P ao efetuar uma volta completa.\\
%   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
%       \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!50!white,dotted] (0,0) grid (19,4);
%   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: don't use the xwatermark package. It is not compatible with a current LaTeX. And don't show so long code, try to make a complete but small example.

Comment: `\begin{minipage}{0\textwidth}` ?? also don't do ` \item {\small Não é permitido o uso de eletrônicos (celulares, calculadoras, etc.);` it makes small text on normal baseline just use `\small` before the list

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I made the changes you suggested, put a smaller code. I saw some topics that there is a problem using xwatermaker with \includegraphics (which I use in my code). I still can't solve the problem of placing the watermark.

Comment: Don't use xwatermark! The package is broken.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @UlrikeFischer. I was able to do what I wanted using another package, \usepackage{background}!